# What happens if error while doing "sed -i --" this is in place change of a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to use `sed -i --` for find and replace few strings in my file. What it there is error while doing the sed command, do the original file get corrupted ? or does it roll back to original file? . I know if i give `sed -i"SUFFIX" --`
it will create a backup file before changes but does it delete the backup file on successful execution of it ? or do we need to do that manually?.

I am looking for something in sed to make changes in place but on error or issue it needs to roll back all the changes until happened until then and give me back the original file as-is.

I can do it like below but looking for any optimized solution:

```
sed 's/abc/def/g' file1 > tmp_file    
cp tmp_file file1
```

Comment: Did you try it with a test file? What happened?

Comment: My guess is, since `-i` operates on a new file and then renames it, that the original file is untouched if there is an error.

Comment: I tried with some data in .csv file. The problem is I am not getting data error. I only got few syntax error but that don't impact the file.

Comment: `cp tmp_file file1` actually creates new error modes: `cp` is not an atomic operation, so it takes time to complete and you can have a partially-written file if it fails partway through. `mv tmp_file file1`, by contrast, is just doing exactly what (a robust implementation of) `sed -i` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a  mis-understanding of how `-i` with the extension works in `sed`. Its sole purpose is to create a backup of the file *as-is* in-case when needed to revert back. Your requirement calls for this perfectly!

The backup file is *never* generated in-case your original command fails out of syntax errors when called. See the following

```
$ echo 'foo' > file
$ ls
file 
$ cat file
foo
$ sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/s' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
$ cat file
foo
$ ls 
file
```

As you can see, even in the forced command failure case, the backup file is not created.

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' file
$ cat file
bar
$ ls
file file.bak
$ cat file.bak
foo
```

But wait a moment, you've replaced incorrectly with `bar`, but you wanted to replace with `foobar`, now revert the file back

```
$ mv file.bak file
$ ls
file
$ cat file
foo
```

Comment: This is generally right, but `--` isn't necessarily an extension -- whether an implementation of `sed` treats it as an option-argument to `-i` or an end-of-options sigil is ambiguous (and off the top of my head, I want to say that behavior varies between GNU and BSD implementations).

Comment: Thank you Inian, In your example "sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s' "  This is syntax error right not the data error. Data don't impact on syntax error but lets say I have 100 rows to find and replace a string ,syntax is correct and after doing 40 replacements  lets say the command failed then what will be my output. I don't know whether I will face this kind of situation but this doubt is bugging me in my head :).

Comment: @settle, because a new file is created from scratch and then renamed over the original, the rename only happens if the *entirety* of the operation succeeds. Though as Inian says, a failure in the middle is unlikely unless you've got hardware faults, stray signals being emitted by buggy software, or other anomalies going around.

Comment: @settle: Why would you expect a failure at middle of replacement? the operation is either success/failure, success  if _all_ the replacements are made.

Comment: ...though if you want full control, the right way to get it is to do it yourself (typically something vaguely like `tempfile=$(mktemp -- "$in.XXXXXX) || exit; if sed -e "$expression" <"$in" >"$tempfile"; then chown --reference="$in" "$tempfile" ||:; chmod --reference="$in" "$tempfile"; mv -- "$tempfile" "$in"; else rm -f -- "$tempfile"; fi`, if you have GNU `chown` and `chmod`). The `-i` argument to `sed` isn't standardized, so the only guarantees that exist about its operation are the ones provided by your specific implementation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You should put that as the answer, I can by no means claim it to be mine. Do add it

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure that's already covered elsewhere in the knowledgebase -- if I were certain that *were* a full and applicable answer, I'd be closing the question as a duplicate.